# Injective function $f_k:\mathcal{P}_k(\mathbb{N})\to \mathbb{N}^k$ for $k\geq 1$ - just a mapping?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have to find an injective function $f_k:\mathcal{P}_k(\mathbb{N})\to \mathbb{N}^k$ for $k\geq1$, where $\mathcal{P}_k(\mathbb{N})$ is the power set of $\mathbb{N}$ with k elements.

I have trouble understanding such a function, as I only can come with: Given a set $A=\{x_1,x_2,...,x_k\}\in\mathcal{P}_k(\mathbb{N})$ with $k$ natural numbers, then $f_k(A)=(x_1,x_2,...,x_k)\in\mathbb{N}^k$. So it is a function that takes $k$ natural numbers and gives a vector/point in the room of natural numbers with orden $k$?

Furthermore, such a function must be injective: When $A_1, A_2, A_3,...$ be sets with $k$ natural numbers, then there union must be countable. So the cardinality of $\#\mathcal{P}_k(\mathbb{N})\leq\#\mathbb{N}$, as this is the definition of countability. When $\#\mathcal{P}_k(\mathbb{N})\leq\#\mathbb{N}$ the function $f$ must be injective.

Comment: In your mind, is it $f_2(\{x\in\Bbb N\,:\, x^2-3x+2=0\})=(1,2)$ or is it $f_2(\{x\in\Bbb N\,:\, x^2-3x+2=0\})=(2,1)$?

Comment: The problem with your function is that in $A$ there is no order and in $f_k(A)$ you have order, you need to be specific about how you order them in $f_k(A)$

Comment: @SaucyO'Path It's the same? :) EDIT: I see the point :)

Comment: @Holo Thank you! So $A=\{x_1 < x_2 < ... < x_k\}$?

Comment: @Frederik you need to explain why you know that the elements of $A$ and be written like this, but this works

Answer (score 1):

Let a$_1$,.. a$_k$ be a well ordering of A and map A to (a$_1$,.. a$_k$).